# What is causing slow file writes on Windows/NTFS?

Tags: windows, ntfs

Here is a simple testrig demonstrating apparent slowness in 'write' file access on Windows/NTFS vs Linux/ext4:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <string.h>

static double time_ms(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timezone tz;
    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);
    int time_now = (int)(tv.tv_sec * 1000 + tv.tv_usec / 1000);
    return (double)time_now / 1000.0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    argc--;
    argv++;
    int line = 0;
    double start = time_ms();
    if (argc < 2)
        return 0;
    int step = atoi(argv[1]);
    int do_sync = (argc > 2 && strcmp(argv[2], "sync") == 0);
    while(1)
    {
        FILE *f = fopen("test", argv[0]);
        if (step == 0)
            line++;
        else for (int j = 0; j < step; j++)
        {
            fprintf(f, "Adding line %08d at %ld\n", line, time(0));
            line++;
        }
        fclose(f);
#ifdef SYNC
        if (do_sync)
            sync();
#endif
        if (line % 1000 == 0)
        {
            double dt = time_ms() - start;
            if (dt)
                printf("Written %s %d lines at %.2f lines/s\n", argv[0], line, line / dt);
        }
    }
}
```

linux compilation:

```
gcc -o append append.c
```

and

```
gcc -o append append.c -DSYNC
```

(cross) compiled on linux with mxe:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-gcc -o append.exe append.c
```

This opens a file, writes a number of lines and closes it. the 'mode' and 'number of lines' can be given on the command line, and also, for linux, 'sync' can be given to perform a sync()

run like this:

```
./append a 10
./append a 100 sync
./append w 1
```

results:

```
lines/sec       windows linux      nosync
append 0        200      6,000    500,000
append 1        150        300    240,000
append 10       1500     3,000  1,800,000
append 100      15000   30,000  5,000,000

write 0         230       300     240,000
write 1         180       280      30,000
write 10        1700     2800     300,000
write 100       17000   28000   2,000,000
```

These tests were run on different hardware for Linux and Windows (10), but the first two columns I believe are comparable -- this shows that Linux+sync() is running around the same speed as windows. but in "normal" operation, without the sync, Linux clearly runs along many thousand times faster as the file writes are being handed off to cache/os/ext4/...

I realise that the *actual* final lines/s written is not as shown, but in the real application those 'slow' writes are blocking and causing noticeable stutter in the user interface.

I have experimented with

- using open()/write() rather than streamed fopen()
- fopen r+ and fseek() rather than "a"
- "native" FileCreate and FileWrite
- compiling with VS

and results vary, but still not anything like the Linux nosync results.

The current "solution" I have is to write the files in a separate thread, which causes its own problems!

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?

Thanks,

Comment: This post may be informative in relation to I/O performance differences between Windows and Linux: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/873#issuecomment-425272829. As mentioned there, things like opening files can be substantially more expensive on Windows, and your code is doing it a lot. If you increase the number of lines you write between opening and closing the file, you should see the numbers improve, as the cost of opening the files becomes less significant relative to writing the data.

Comment: The answer to the question you avoid asking is: Use [immutable and persistent data structures for C++](https://github.com/arximboldi/immer).

Comment: Iridium: thanks for link, that seems to describe my findings well. We don't have a lot of options to wait for many more than a few lines to arrive, so we may be stuck with the other-thread option